loading dynamic content in sub view and pass to master page in laravel
I have created a menu bar with dynamic menus. It is working fine when I load it separately as blade template page.
But when I include it in master page layout shows error.
route file::
Route::resource('menu',MenuController::class);
Route::resource('submenu',SubMenuController::class);
Route::view('master','layouts.layout');

My menu controller::
 public function index()
    {
        $menus = menu::all();
        return view('layouts.include-menu', compact('menus'));
    }

layouts.include-menu.blade.php page // removed all other details
<header id="header" class="header-two">
  <div class="site-navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
              <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light p-0">
                
                <div class="logo">
                    <a class="d-block" href="index-2.html">
                      <img loading="lazy" src="images/logo.png" alt="Constra">
                    </a>
                </div><!-- logo end -->

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                
                <div id="navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto align-items-center">
                    @foreach ($menus as $item)
                    @if (count($item->submenus)>0)
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ $item->menu_name }}<span class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></span></a>
                        @foreach ($item->submenus as $submenu)
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="index.html">{{$submenu->submenu_name}}</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        @endforeach 
                    </li>
                    @else
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">{{ $item->menu_name }}</a>
                    </li>
                    @endif
                    @endforeach   
                    </ul>
                </div>
              </nav>
          </div>
          <!--/ Col end -->
        </div>
        <!--/ Row end -->
    </div>
    <!--/ Container end -->
  </div>
  <!--/ Navigation end -->
</header>
<!--/ Header end -->

This page is loading fine when I load it separately as blade template page.
But when I include it in master page getting error::
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   @include('layouts.include-head')
</head>
<body>
    <!--/ main div of the page -->
    <div class="body-inner">
    <!-- Header start -->
    <header id="header" class="header-two">
        @include('layouts.include-menu')
    </header> <!-- Header end -->



    <footer id="footer" class="footer bg-overlay">
        @include('layouts.include-footer')
    </footer>

    </div> <!--/ main div of the page ends -->
</body>
</html>

error showing on C:\xampp\htdocs\gva_app\resources\views\layouts\include-menu.blade.php ::
Undefined variable $menus 
 @foreach ($menus as $item)

Why is it so?

if you need the menu on every page, use https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/views#view-composers or make a method directly usable in the menu blade.

From laravel docs: "All variables that are available to the parent view will be made available to the included view", so the $menus should be available in the partial view as well. If you do dd($menus) just before @include('layouts.include-menu'), do you see the data that you need?

@zlatan I did not get what you are trying to say... All variables that are available to the parent view will be made available to the included view", so the $menus should be available in the partial view as well. If you do dd($menus) just before @include('layouts.include-menu') please can you explain. thank you

I was referring to official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/blade#including-subviews
As for the second part, I meant if you could add {{dd($menus)}} just before the @include('layouts.include-menu') in you code, so that you can see if there is a value in that variable at all

@zlatan doing {{dd($menu)}} showing the same error. Undefined variable

Was that a typo, since your variable is not $menu but $menus?

sorry typo error... {{dd($menus)}} also giving the error. undefined variable thank you for your concern

You can now include the include-menu and pass the $menus variable
<header id="header" class="header-two">
    @include('layouts.include-menu', ['menus' => $menus])
</header>

